# wordpress вывести список рубрик

Tags: wordpress

Пытаюсь вывести список рубрик с помощью

```
<?php wp_list_categories('depth=1');?>
```

Но выводит только одну рубрику, то есть первая которая без рубрики.. Остальные игнорирует хоть добавляй хоть сохраняй.. не видит. как можно вывести нормально все родительские рубрики?

Comment: Вам нужно вывести все рубрики первого уровня? Рубрики не пустые? Потому что параметр `hide_empty` по умолчанию равен 1, то есть пустые категории не выводятся.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&include=id рубрик&title_li=');?
```

orderby(строка)
Сортировать список можно по определенным критериям. Например по количеству постов в каждой категории или по названию категорий. Есть следующие критерии:

1. ID - сортировка по ID;
2. name - сортировка по названию (по умолчанию);
3. slug - сортировка по алт. имени (slug);
4. count - по количеству записей в категории;
5. term_group - по группе.

По умолчанию: 'name'

include(строка)
Выводит списком только указанные категории. Указывать нужно ID категорий через запятую.

title_li(строка)
Установит заголовок списка. Если изменить этот параметр на '', то заголовок не будет выводиться вовсе.
По умолчанию: 'Категории'